# Type curly brackets on Debian running on mac

Tags: linux, debian, osx, virtualbox

I have searched for this problem for a while and can not find an answer anywhere.

I am currently running a Debian on virtual box on a mac. How do i type the "Alt Gr" Characters like curly brackets?

Comment: Er, which keyboard layout?  Every keyboard I have seen has e. g. `{` being a shifted `[`.

Comment: I have a Swedish keyboard layout. I have to alt + shift for {. Is it possible to change the keyboard langue in Debian?

Comment: It is, but there is a handy shortcut for the sequence you describe.  Press and release Escape, then press shift and the other unspecified key.  An escape usually tells a terminal to interpret the next character as though it has the Meta (i. e. Alt) bit set.  To clarify, for example:  Alt+shift+3 is the same in most terminals as Escape, shift+3.

Comment: It did not work for me, Does this only work in the console or does it also work in emacs for example?

Comment: @DopeGhoti not everybody uses US layout. On *most* layouts, at least some, if not all of the `[]{}<>@^\|~` ASCII symbols require alt-gr modifier, because their languages opt for "one letter one sound" encoding instead of using multi-letter combinations to encode all the sounds on a limited alphabet. mac keyboard is quite problematic in this regard, so I'd probably choose an on-screen keyboard inside the virtual machine, or set up `xmodmap`. Anyway, other users know better, as I see from the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Debian assumes PC-style keyboards. Since you're using a mac, you're not using that, so you need to tell Debian that. To do so, you need to modify `/etc/default/keyboard` so it contains the following:

```
XKBMODEL=macintosh
XKBLAYOUT=se
```

You can then use the same keys on your Debian machine as you would use on OS X.